# Using interactive commands with bash -s

Tags: bash, shell, interactive

I am trying to execute a bash script in this way:

```
bash -s < my_script
```

The reason, for context, is to run the script remotely through SSH. I realized that the script I want to run includes some commands that can prompt the user for input, under certain rare conditions. So I decided to try and understand how that would work out with bash -s.

I wrote a simple script like this:

```
cat
echo "finished"
```

and got the output:

```
echo "finished"
```

My understanding is that, since the script itself is the stdin, the `cat` command simply starts reading the rest of the script.

But, if I just add an "if" to the script, the result changes.  So if I run this:

```
if [ true ]
then
        cat
        echo "finished"
fi
```

I get this output:

```
finished
```

I don't understand what causes this difference.

Comment: `</dev/tty` is your friend in this context, if you want to separate the concept of the TTY from stdin -- `cat </dev/tty` will always read from the terminal, never from the `my_script` file (unless you've gone out of your way to confuse the issue by using a tool like `unbuffer` that emulates a TTY with content actually coming from stdin).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It sounds like they're using this to run the script over an `ssh` connection, which means the script *will* be coming over /dev/tty.

Comment: @GordonDavisson In general, unless you do something silly (like run `ssh -tt` or use an invocation mode designed for interactive use noninteractively), that just means there is no `/dev/tty` at all; so you get a nice clean failure to open `/dev/tty`, instead of successfully opening it but then having script text in place of user input. Providing a remote command line to run, as in `ssh host 'bash -s'`, disables ssh's TTY emulation support by default.

Comment: (that said, if that's the case the OP is designing for, I'd just pass the whole script in the command line and not try to read any part of it from stdin at all; on modern systems argv is allowed to be well over 100kB, so the command line should be perfectly workable).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bash` reads (at least) an entire *statement* at a time, no matter how many lines of the file that entails. which in your latter example is the entire `if` statement. So by the time `cat` is executed, there is nothing left for it to read on standard input.

You would see the same result, for example, with

```
{
  cat
  echo "finished"
}
```

as everything inside and including the `{...}` is a single (compound) statement.

In the first example, the first statement is `cat` by itself, leaving the `echo` statement in standard input for `cat` to read.

Comment: This seems accurate.  I tried adding `echo "some more stuff"` to the end of the script and got `echo "some more stuff"`
`finished`

Answer (score 3):

To add to [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner)'s answer, you can get a clear image of what's going on by trying to write the script manually to the shell.

If you write `cat` and press enter, the cursor goes on the next line and there is no prompt, meaning that the shell is waiting for a line in `stdin`. Typing `echo "finished"` and pressing enter feeds `cat` a line containing `echo "finished"`, which is promptly printed back in the shell (the current `stdout`). What you see is this:

```
[xxx@yyy ~]$ cat
echo "finished"
echo "finished" # this one was printed by cat
# and now your cursor is here
```

If you kill it and type `if [ true ]`, instead, you get a `>` prompt on the new line. That next line will be a statement, so writing `cat` all alone on one line will result in no output to `stdout`, since `cat` got nothing from the `stdin`. Again, what you get (if you feed it an `EOF` at the end) is this:

```
[xxx@yyy ~]$ if [ true ]
> then
> cat
> echo "finished"
> fi # here you press enter, cursor goes to newline, then CTRL+D to feed an EOF
finished
```

The most clarifying thing is to retrieve the latest issued command by pressing the arrow up. You'll get:

```
[xxx@yyy ~]$ if [ true ]; then cat; echo "finished"; fi
```

This is what `bash` actually sees, and it's pretty self-explanatory about why `cat` is not passing `echo "finished"` to the `stdout` this time.